# Datatables pagination control not visible

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, datatables

As I'm using Angular, I have made a datatable initialization in Angular document.ready function as shown below:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#orders-table1').DataTable({
        "order": [[0, "desc"]],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "paging": true,
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Administration/GetOrders",
            "type": "POST",
            "datatype": "json",
            "success": function (data) {
                var datastring = JSON.stringify(data);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Administration/GetOrderRowPartialView',
                    data: {
                        objekt: datastring
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $("#orders-table1-body").html($compile(data)($scope)); //the data is the partial view containing many partial views
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Code explanation:**

When the page is loaded, table initialization starts with *serverSide* property set to true. The first ajax call calls the controller action and gets the data in json format.

Considering that each row in the table has to be the partial view (Razor, ASP.NET), I have created one partial view (row collection) which contains many partial views (rows).

So, that's why I have another Ajax call. The one that receives the data from the previous one and creates the partial view (collection of rows) with many partial views included (rows) and renders it in the table body.

Everything works fine, except I don't see the pagination numbers.

**Here is the server side code, two controller actions:**

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrders()
{
    INarudzbeBL INarudzbeBL = BLFactory.KreirajInstancuNarudzba<INarudzbeBL>();
    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw").FirstOrDefault();
    var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
    var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();

    var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
    var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();

    int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
    int skip = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
    int totalRecords = 0;

    var narudzbe = INarudzbeBL.DohvatiSveNarudzbe();

    totalRecords = narudzbe.Count();
    var data = narudzbe.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

    NarudzbaToCustomNarudzbaMapper narudzbaToCustomNarudzbaMapper = new NarudzbaToCustomNarudzbaMapper();
    List<TP1.CustomMappers.AdministrationOrders.NarudzbaCustomViewModel> narudzbaCustomViewModels = narudzbaToCustomNarudzbaMapper.MapNarudzbaToCustomNarudzba(data);

    NarudzbaCustomViewModelHolder narudzbaCustomViewModelHolder = new NarudzbaCustomViewModelHolder();
    narudzbaCustomViewModelHolder.NarudzbaCustomViewModels = narudzbaCustomViewModels;

    return Json(narudzbaCustomViewModelHolder);
}

[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetOrderRowPartialView(string objekt)
{
    NarudzbaCustomViewModelHolder narudzbaCustomViewModelHolder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NarudzbaCustomViewModelHolder>(objekt);

    return PartialView("~/Views/Administration/Partial/Orders/OrdersTablePartialView.cshtml", narudzbaCustomViewModelHolder.NarudzbaCustomViewModels);
}
```

The first one is for getting the data in JSON format, and the second one is to create a partial view with received data, one for each ajax call.

**This is how the table footer looks like:**

[image: Table overview]

I have included the necessary scripts and style files.

So, the question is, why I don't see the pagination numbers? What am I missing?

Comment: 1) You cannot use the success callback in DataTables ajax 2) it is unclear what you are trying to do in the next ajax 3) try take a look at http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, when I put the dataSrc callback instead of success, everything shows the same, except now I got an error "Cannot read property length of undefined". First Ajax call is for getting the data in JSON format, which then I send to controller action (via second ajax call). The function creates the partial view, which I render it to the datatable. The table rows are in partial view form because they are fully customized as you can see on the screenshot. Also, you can see that the third column contains few buttons, which updates the row on click, thats why I use PV

Comment: See **https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc**